# Converting JavaScript inner object to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to convert an "inner object" to a string to then 'split' it into an array.  I might be using the terms wrong.

```
async componentDidMount() {
try{
  let gauge_data = await gauge.read('VersionItems');
  let {VersionItems} = gauge_data;    
  // console.log(VersionItems);
  VersionItems = VersionItems.replaceAll(/'/g,'"'); // converting all ' to "" through regex because JSON.parse works only for double quotes
  VersionItems = JSON.parse(VersionItems);
  // console.log(VersionItems);
  let {unit_version} = VersionItems.linuxVersions; // --- this does not return anything.... unit_version is 'undefined'
  console.log(unit_version);
  let {unit1_version} = VersionItems.linuxVersions[0];   // --- this does not return anything.... unit_version is 'undefined'
   console.log(unit1_version);
  let unit_versions = unit_version.split(',');  // this does not work since unit_version is undefined.. but it is what I want to do.
  console.log(unit_versions);
  this.setState({
    value : VersionItems.applicationVersions,
    dbInfo_revision : VersionItems.applicationVersions[0].dbInfo_rev,
    dbInfo_timestamp : VersionItems.applicationVersions[0].dbInfo_date,
    Company_version : VersionItems.unit_versions[0],
    linux_version : VersionItems.unit_versions[1] // This used to be VersionItems.linuxVersions and worked fine
  })
}catch(err){
  console.log('ERROR IN VERSION PAGE -',err)
}
```

}

The VersionItems has the correct contents. The applicationVersions is an array of 16 items and the   linuxVersion is a string with about 50 characters. There is a single "," after the first 15 characters. I have blanked out some identifying information. I think I am very close but fail to understand the nuances of JavaScript and React. In the setState the VersionItem.linuxVersion was referenced and work properly. I did not write any of this code.  I am sure this has been answered before I just cannot describe it the correct way.

[image]

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I don't see `unit_version` anywhere in the object, why do you try to access it?

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to cut some slack here for an unfamiliar stack, but I can't follow this at all. You've got a not-quite-JSON data response...why? Why is the server/hardware/whatever returning something that is almost but not quite JSON? `VersionItems.linuxVersions` is an array, it's not going to have a `unit_version` property. `VersionItems.linuxVersions[0]` is a string, likewise not going to have a `unit_version` property. Not sure why you'd expect either one of them to, or what that property is supposed to be.

Comment: Can't you just use VersionItems without the replace and without the parse?

Comment: I *think* (and this is kind of a guess since your question has the issues I mentioned previously) that you meant to write `let [unit1_version] = VersionItems.linuxVersions; unit1_version = unit1_version.split(',');` (note square brackets instead of curly in the destructuring assignment) which can be simplified`let unit1_version = VersionItems.linuxVersions[0].split(',');`

Comment: Await won't work unless parent function has async. I'd suggest for starters put all that code in componentDidMount into a wrapper function.

Comment: @JaredSmith I will try the [unit1_version]..   I thought I could assign a new variable to the contents of VersionItems.linuxVersions. Then operate on the new variable...

Comment: @James. Maybe I just inherited the code. In many other places they do this "replace" and parse. So I didn't know any better. I will try to skip them and see what happens.

Comment: The curly brackets in `let {unit_version} = thing...` mean you want to assign a local variable called unit_version to the value of thing.unit_version.  You probably don't want the `{}` in most of your let statements.

Comment: @RyanButon you can, but not the way you were trying to. LinuxVersions is an array so you can index into it and assign it to the contents of a variable. But you were using *object* destructuring, not array destructuring. Since arrays (like everything else in JS) *are* objects you tried to pull out the object property, which doesn't exist on arrays (so you get undefined).

Comment: @JaredSmith the [] worked. I did not know about the {} requirement. Thanks.